# Android Studio show a dialog after start game

Tags: android, dialog

I am currently programming a game and have before the button "start game" expresses a separate dialog appears where the game is explained. I can still get it by myself! But I would like this dialog per player only once appears and afterwards never again! Does anyone know an approach?

Comment: Are you using any kind of memory storage to save the player's data (points, scores, etc)?

Comment: Yes I have a server where the score of the player and the game name itself is stored in it

Comment: So you can store a boolean there, like "isFirstTime" which stores true if the its the player's first time. And then store false and it isn't. Or you could use SharedPreferences, as  @Isaac sugested on the answer below.

Comment: select answer if helped..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of code provided by @Isaac Payne, I'm modifying the code for `Dialog`.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Context mContext = this.getApplicationContext();
                //0 = mode private. only this app can read these preferences
        mPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs", 0);


        // the rest of your app initialization code goes here
        if(getFirstRun()) {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(your_activity_context.this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //if not title window required.
        dialog.setContentView(your_layout_to_show_as_window);

        // initialize your views from the layout            
        setRan();
        dialog.show();
        }
    }

    public boolean getFirstRun() {
        return mPrefs.getBoolean("firstRun", true);
    }

    public void setRan() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = mPrefs.edit();
        edit.putBoolean("firstRun", false);
        edit.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But the method setRan is never used and when i start the App the second time is the Dialog there..

Comment: Yes mistake, put `setRan` after `dialog.show();`. It will work.  Must upvote and accept if helped...

Comment: I try it when i am back from school! But thank you for youre big help! :)

Comment: Can i ask you more questions if i have a question bro? :)

Comment: What happened @jordie ?

Comment: Okay i have a MainActivity in my MainActivity is the code from youre good answer ;) and i have Main2Activity with activitymain2 so i want when the application starts that the Dialog comes with an animation. I can see the Pic but the animation dont work...the dialog is activitymain2 and the code from the animation is in Main2Activity but it dont work. When i put the animation on the activitymain and the code in MainActivity than it worked..and the animation is a wizard in the dialog and he speak sorry for my English i am german bro :D @W4R10CK

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

E.g:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Context mContext = this.getApplicationContext();
                //0 = mode private. only this app can read these preferences
        mPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs", 0);


        // the rest of your app initialization code goes here
        if(getFirstRun()) {
            //Show dialog
        }
    }

    public boolean getFirstRun() {
        return mPrefs.getBoolean("firstRun", true);
    }

    public void setRan() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = mPrefs.edit();
        edit.putBoolean("firstRun", false);
        edit.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean i press the Button "Start Game" and then appears a Dialog xml file where i explain the game. And that was it